# Place math operation or values side by side in database Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm just giving one dataset example of what I need to do with a real dataset at my company with python/pandas.

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'product_code': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'price': range(6),
                   'region': rng.randint(0, 10, 6)},
                   columns = ['product_code', 'price', 'region'])

df
```

---

It will give us:
[image]

How do I place products showing side by side the current price, the minimun price and the max price like this:
[image]

I've just tried a groupby and aggregate function but I cound't get what I want.

```
df.groupby('product_code').aggregate({
                              'price' :'price',
                              'price':'min',
                              'price': 'max'
                            })
```

Comment: Actually I'm not calculating anything, just using the functions min and max properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
min_ = df.groupby('product_code')['price'].min()
max_ = df.groupby('product_code')['price'].max()

df['min'] = df['product_code'].apply(lambda x: min_[x])
df['max'] = df['product_code'].apply(lambda x: max_[x])
```